# Get image properties with Jython

Tags: image, jython

I am using Jython to move images around and organise them.  I would like to extract some information from the images like dimensions and file size.

How would I go about doing this with Jython?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Python Image Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).